# How to get records by multiple values?

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following table: (note that target is only unique for illustration)

```
a  | b  | TSD   | target
---|----|-------|-------
a1 | b1 |     1 |    1
a2 | b1 |     1 |    2
a1 | b2 |     1 |    3
a2 | b2 |     1 |    4
a1 | b1 |     2 |    5
a2 | b1 |     2 |    6
a1 | b2 |     2 |    7
a2 | b2 |     2 |    8
```

Now I have a select like

```
SELECT target FROM tab
WHERE a = :val-A
  AND b = :val-B
  AND TSD <= :val-TSD
ORDER BY TSD desc
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

So for the inputs `a1` `b1` `1` I get `1`, for `a1` `b2` `42` I get `7`

Now I would like to change that query so that I can provide multiple of those inputs to be queried at once - (if that's possible) (order of records does not matter, I just need the *newest* record.)

I'd target something like this:

```
SELECT a, b, target FROM tab
WHERE (a, b) in (
  (:val-a1, :val-b1)
 ,(:val-a2, :val-b2)
-- ...
 ,(:val-an, :val-bn)
  )
  AND TSD <= :val-TSD -- How to do the < per input?

FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY; -- How to only get the newest one per input?
```

I want to merge 50 of those calls into one `SELECT` statement. 
`UNION` all the 50 rows together is not an option.

*(this will be inside a COBOL program with DB2)*

Comment: Have you considered inserting your parameters into a table *(One row per set of three parameters)*?  Then you could join your data table to your parameter table and process as many individual queries you like in the batch?

Comment: @MatBailie Can you provide it as a query? I see the approach with inner joining, but still don't know how then I can get max one record per input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no DB2 expert, but from what I can see it supports `ROW_NUMBER()` which is the "usual" way to approach "greatest-n-pre-group". *(You want the greatest 1 per group)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    param.id   AS param_id,
    data.a,
    data.b
    data.TSD,
    data.target,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY param.id ORDER BY data.TSD DESC)   AS data_row_id
  FROM
    data
  INNER JOIN
    param
      ON  data.a    = param.a
      AND data.b    = param.b
      AND data.TSD <= param.TSD
)
  AS results
WHERE
  results.data_row_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*, t.target
from param p, table(
select t.target 
from tab t 
where t.a=p.a and t.b=p.b and t.tsd<=p.tsd 
order by t.tsd desc
fetch first 1 row only
) t;
```

Here is an example of "parameterized" subselect. Logically this works as follows:

For each row of a table with parameters "param" the corresponding select statement inside the brackets is executed using the "parameters" passed. "Order by" and "Fetch first" clauses are used there to select needed rows only.

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.